# Debug a Python script with sys.stdin in WingIDE

Tags: debugging, wing-ide

In command line, i run my script as follows:

```
cat sample.log | python -B main.py logsource
```

How do i debug the main.py and provide:

- sample.log as `sys.stdin`
- `-B` for python
- `logsource` as input parameter (`sys.argv[1]`)

I'm using Python 3 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Piping a file to stdin isn't supported when launching a debug process from Wing.  You can, however:

- Add -B to the Python Options under Debug/Execute tab in Project Properties (from the Project menu)
- Add the logsource arg under the Debug/Execute tab of File Properties for main.py (right click on it and select Properties)

Another option is to add 'import wingdbstub' to main.py as described in http://wingware.com/doc/debug/debugging-externally-launched-code to start debug.  Then you can just type the command line as above and don't need to set anything in Project Properties or File Properties.